# privateRuntimeConfig values are undefined under plugins

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

History, I'm wondering how to use privateRuntimeConfig in Nuxt under `plugins`.
I want to run firebase initialize function passing env but `$config` seems undefined.
Am I missing something?

// nuxt.config.js

```js
privateRuntimeConfig: {
  firebase: {
    apiKey: process.env.apiKey,
    authDomain: process.env.authDomain,
    databaseURL: process.env.databaseURL,
    projectId: process.env.projectId,
    storageBucket: process.env.storageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.messagingSenderId
  }
}
```

// plugins/firebase.ts

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp($config); // error: $config is undefined
}

export default firebase($config);
```

Comment: Why are you expecting it to be defined?  What value do you think it should have?

Comment: I thought `$config` holds the values defined under `privateRuntimeConfig` in nuxt.config.js.

Comment: ↑ as is shown https://nuxtjs.org/guide/runtime-config#usage

Answer (score 2):

You can access **privateRuntimeConfig** variables from the server-side lifecycle hook of nuxt: like NuxtServerInit, Validate(), asyncData() or fetch(context)

nuxt-lifecycle : https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle

If both private and public runtime config have the same value, private runtime overrides the public.

let me explain by a simple code;

**nuxt.config.js**

```
...
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  API_KEY: '1245',
},
privateRuntimeConfig: {
  API_KEY: 'AIzaSyAxwq', //Real API-Key
},
...
```

**plugins/helpers.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default function({ app }, inject) {

  const helpers = {
    getApiKey() {
      return app.$config.API_KEY;
    }
  };
  inject('helpers', helpers);
}
```

**pages/test.vue**

```
...
<script>
  export default {
    asyncData(context) {
      console.log(context.$helpers.getApiKey()) --> displays: AIzaSyAxwq
    },
    created() {
      console.log(this.$helpers.getApiKey()) --> displays: 12345
    }
  }
</script>
...
```

Comment: So much packed into this answer. Thank you!